# Refactoring or using Design Pattern on Switch-Case-Smell

Tags: java, design-patterns, optimization, junit, refactoring

Since I am currently dealing with Design Patterns and Refactoring some Legacy Code to write some JUnit-Tests, I am looking through my project, where I could apply it.

I found one method in one class, where I have a very long switch-case-statement. Of course this is a horrible scenario for unit-testing, since I need to create a test for every statement.

Now I thought about applying the Strategypattern. But the problem is, I have 30 different cases. That would mean I would have to create 30 classes. Is this advised, or should I consider some other way of refactoring? Morover the switch case is inside two for-loop, since it's an Excel-table.

Here is an excerpt of my method:

```
switch (column) {
    case CASE1:
        excelUtil.setCell(row, col++, item.getSomething(), styles[0]);
        break;
    case CASE2:
        excelUtil.setCell(row, col++, order.getSomething(), styles[0]);
        break;
    case CASE3:
        excelUtil.setCell(row, col++, order.getSomethingElse(), styles[0]);
        break;
    case CASE4:
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(order.getSomething())) {
            try {
                //do something before setting cell
                excelUtil.setCell(row, col++, soldToName, styles[0]);
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
                excelUtil.setCell(row, col++, "", styles[0]);
            }
        }
        else {
            excelUtil.setCell(row, col++, "", styles[0]);
        }
        break; //.. and so on
```

Comment: I think you should try strategy pattern in the first place. Having 30 strategies isn't bad, maybe you find some relations between them and then you could apply different pattern and so on..

Comment: How do you get the value of `column`?

Comment: By the way, I don't think that you should use `col++` in a try/catch block, since you might end up writing one column further over than you expect if an exception occurs. You should probably write the logic with the try/catch to determine the cell's String value, and then do the call to `setCell(row, col++, value, styles[0])` after.

Comment: @AndyTurner From a List I pass to the method. The switch-case is surrounded with 'for(ExportField column : columns)'

Comment: You still should have a unit test for every condition in the switch. That way when you refactor the code you will know that you haven't broken anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the strategy pattern is the right choice in this situation.** Ensure that the state tracking logic (e.g. `col++`) is not leaked into the strategies.

With strategies in place, the strategy selection can then be moved to a dictionary: Create a dictionary that maps from `column` to a strategy, and use the dictionary in place of the switch-case. This works because the strategies all implement the same interface.

Comment: But I am currently facing a problem, which I am currently not getting. How do I now tell the method, which Strategy-class to use?

Comment: Thanks. So all in all just to verify, it is no problem to have 30 classes, just for strategy?

Comment: Yes, there is no issue with the number of classes. Many small classes are better than one big mess of a class. Also, classes don't have a performance impact.

Comment: Ok. So last but not least I need to check my dependencies. Because in the switch-statements I sometimes for example call `myService.getValue()` so I need to look how to best pass the myService instance to my Strategy.